# Why is Restangular sending 2 requests for each resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, restangular

I like for Restangular to send just one request but it keeps making two. In addition if I'm sending a request with params its will send as undefined for the first request then define for the second. My Im doing so as seen below, what could be causing it to do this?

```
 .service('SomeStuffService', function ( $q, _,Restangular,$localStorage){
    return {
        getSomeStuffs: function() {
          var dfd = $q.defer();

          setTimeout(function() {
              Restangular.one('stuff').get().then(function(stuffObj) {
              $localStorage.stuff =stuffObj.stuff;
                dfd.resolve(stuffObj.stuff);
          },2000)
        });
          return dfd.promise;
        }
      }
    })
```

resolve before state loads

```
.state('app.stuff-state', {
      url: '/stuff',
.....
    resolve: {
        regions: function($stateParams,SomeStuffService) {
          return SomeStuffService.getSomeStuffs();
        }
      }
```

in my controller

```
$scope.stuff = $localStorage.stuff||SomeStuffService.getSomeStuffs()
```

Comment: Why would you ever need to call `getSomeStuffs` in your controller? Your controller should have `regions` injected. Also prefer `$timeout` to `setTimeout` with Angular apps.

Comment: Is this cross domain and the first request is an OPTIONS preflight? If so that's the browser doing it, and you can't do anything about it as it's part of of CORS

Comment: oh @AndyGaskell you're right. I have ` $localStorage.stuff =stuffObj.stuff;` that already put it in localStorage. And @charlietfl yes is is cross domain and l guess Restangular is using OPTIONS and thats not allowed for my requests (only GET), How can I get it to simple send a GET? can I do anything about that (with RestangularProvider right?)?

Comment: @qizzacious it is not related with restangular it wont change as long as you don't change backend... if you wish try another library ngResource or $http you will still send options first then request...